# Keycode for Android minimize soft keyboard button

Tags: android, android-keypad

I'm using the soft keyboard for Android 3.2. The problem is I can't find the `keyCode` for the button on the bottom left that minimizes the keyboard.

I used a switch case for `onKeyDown` to display the `keyCode` and it seems to be the only one without a value. I figured it would have the same code as the back button since that is what it replaces but no such luck.

Comment: It may be the Enter (Return?) button... as I believe that is the one for me that says "Done," or "Next" most of the time.

Comment: What do you mean by 'Without a value'? You get a value in the `onKeyDown` method, even if the `KeyEvent` class has no constant describing it, you **do** have a value.

Comment: are your method `onKeyDown()` is beeing called or not? If it does - you can a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just the back button. You can just do this by overriding its behavior, with :

```
 InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
 mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

and :

```
@Override
boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
//hide the soft keyboard
 super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```